# VS Designer always throws the Exception "The x Property doesn't have a get/set method"

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having this problem with the VS Designer that makes it impossible to work with it.
What it happens is that I'm editing my XAML code, and the VS Designer will throw an exception at some point, with a StackTrace like this:

> InvalidOperationException: The Property "MyObject.MyProperty" doesn't have a get method

StackTrace:

> at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Metadata.LocalClrPropertyImplementation.GetValue(Object target)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Metadata.ClrPropertyReferenceStep.GetValue(Object valueToInspect)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Metadata.PropertyReference.TryGetValue(Object& value, ReferenceStep referenceStep, Object target)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Metadata.PropertyReference.PartialGetValue(Object target, Int32 initialStepIndex, Int32 finalStepIndex)
>      at [...]

...and it goes on for another 50 lines at least.

The Property in question is something like this:

```
private bool _MyProperty = true;

public bool MyProperty
{
    set
    {
        if (_MyProperty != value)
        {
            // Do a few things here
            this._MyProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works fine, and I have dozens of things like this in my project, VS has never bothered me with them before.
If I try to close and open VS again it will let me work for a while, and then it will eventually start throwing this errors again.

I tried cleaning the Solution from Compile > Clean Solution, it doesn't work.

I really don't know what's the problem here.
I mean, I created that property like 2 months ago, why is VS only telling me that now?

Is there a fix for this, or do I have to manually add all those useless get/set methods in every single parameter I have created?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of this property `MyProperty` anywhere in your application? What does all those `GetValue()` methods do?

Comment: Do you intentionally have write-only properties?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky No I'm not, and I was just changing the layout of some controls in XAML when I got that exception. And it's happening in different pages at random.

Comment: @RufusL Yes I do, I just use them to set via code behind some values to some elements in my UserControls, passing those values via XAML

Comment: Do you have any DependencyProperties defined?

Comment: Are you using any third party controls? Like telerik or devexpress?

Comment: @RufusL I'm using DependencyProperties on Properties I want to Bind, but for these few ones I just needed to set them to a value passed from XAML, so it was just a Property with a private field and some operations inside the set method

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Yes, I'm using the following libraries: Telerik Universal UI, DropNetRT, InTheHand.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer, Live SDK, Newtonsoft.Json, ShakeGestureLibrary, SQLite for WP8.1, WinRTXamlToolkit and WriteableBitmapEx

Comment: how did this question get 5 upvotes? Your property does not have a getter and you probably bind to it. The error message makes it kind of obvious...

Comment: It has 5 upvotes because as I explained in my question, I'm sure I'm not accessing that property, and I'm not using any bindings on it, I just use the set property in my XAML. Also, even though there is that error, the app compiles and runs fine, and once restarted, VS doesn't give that error anymore, so that's not a fault in my code, but in VS itself.
I was just curious to know why.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite obvious, according to your error message:"The Property "MyObject.MyProperty" doesn't have a get method", you must be using MyProperty by access MyObject.MyProperty somewhere, you need to check that, 
and one more method is that if you don't want to expose MyProperty outside of this class, you should use 'private set', it's really odd that you don't have getter while you have a public setter,hope can give u some help

Comment: As I said, I'm sure I'm not using that property in reading mode anywhere in my code, and restarting VS solves the problem. Plus, the compiler gives 0 errors, and the app runs fine. VS just gets messed up at random with that error, right now it's like 10 days it's working fine for example.

Comment: if that so, have you done serialization on that object or maybe serialization is triggered in some condition? Serialization need both getter and setter, it's very common throw exception when your object is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced windows forms designer faults (VS 2015) using write only properties (defined as write only).  I could only get the form back on display by making the property read write (set/get).

The only reason I didn't turn this into a method was that I needed is "settable" at design time.

Hope this helps someone - or me when I forget and find this post again :)